# Application to use relations between entities to form solution

Tags: java, android, dictionary, relational-database

Sorry if my description sounds a bit ambiguous, but I'm just hoping someone can lead me in the right direction.

I am designing an app that for a card game I have in mind, will allow you to put in two card names, and from that, the app will determine an "assumed ruling" from the rulings of the two cards. This is to alleviate any ambiguity in the descriptions of effects on the cards. The rulings of cards, are for the most part written, but they are not on the cards themselves. The app is to allow people, so if they get stuck because of ambiguous wording, can just enter the two card names, and out comes a rulings.

For instance, CardA says "this card gets a super boost when battling", and CardB says "when battlings, stop all super boosts others get". When you enter CardA and CardB in the app, it will say something of the sort of "CardA's super boost will not activate when battling CardB." Obviously this wasn't very ambgious, but its just an example.

I was thinking that the program could take out key phrases like other card names, "battle", "defense", "attack", "return to hand", and compare them to find "related" phrases from the other cards. And based on this, formulate some conclusion by piecing together a sentence from the already written ruling for each card (which the app will access). Of course, if CardA is mentioned in the ruling of CardB, all I'd have to do is print the sentence mentioning the other.

I was thinking this may be a tad similar to how Google figures out what you like by reading your emails.

Basically, I need help understanding how to make the relations between the cards, and how to formulate an English sentence from the comparison.

I don't expect anyone to sit here and tell me how to do anything, but I just need a push in the right direction. Any help you be nice. Thanks.